# Why do i have a mapping exception?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

Right now i want to make a small java application, in order to learn the hibernate framework. But it gives me the `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: model.Book column: author (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`. And if I delete the author column mapping from entities.hbm.xml, then it shows me that sql message "SELEC FROM ..." but after that, it gives me 2 exceptions:

- `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query`
- `java.sql.SQLException: No database selected.`

Can anyone help me?

**hibernate.cfg.xml file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name = "hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name = "dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name = "show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping resource = "entities.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**entities.hbm.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package = "model">

   <class name = "Genre" table = "virtual bookcase.genres">
      <id name = "id" column = "idGenres" type = "long">
        <generator class = "increment"/>
      </id>   
      <property name = "name" column = "name" type = "string"/>
      <set name = "books" table = "books" cascade = "all-delete-orphan">
        <key column = "idGenres" not-null = "true" />
        <one-to-many class = "Book"/>
      </set>
   </class>

   <class name = "Book" table = "virtual bookcase.books">
        <id name = "id" column = "idBooks" type = "long">
         <generator class = "increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name = "title" column = "title" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "author" column = "author" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "publisher" column = "author" type = "string"/>
        <property name = "pages" column = "pages" type = "short"/>
        <property name = "borrowed" column = "borrowed" type = "byte"/>
        <property name = "borrowedTo" column = "borrowedTo" type = "string"/>
   </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Java entities:**

```
public class Genre
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Book> books;

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Book> getBooks()
    {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(Set<Book> books)
    {
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**getBooks() method:**

```
public Set<Book> getBooks()
    {
        Set<Book> books = null;

        connect();

        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();

        Query q = s.createQuery("FROM Book");
        books = new TreeSet<Book>(q.list());

        for (Book b : books)
            System.out.println(b);

        s.close();
        sf.close();

        disconnect();

        return books;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two properties mapped to the column author:

```
<property name="author" column="author" type="string"/>
<property name="publisher" column="author" type="string"/>
```

To solve the second error append the database name to your JDBC connection URL:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
    jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname
</property>
```

Reading through your sources further I stumbled  over your getBooks()-method. You should not create a SessionFactory every time you need a Hibernate Session. The creation of the SessionFactory is too expensive (measured in time) to perform this every time. A minimum solution would be a Singleton class you can ask for the SessionFactory:

```
public class SessionFactoryUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private SessionFactoryUtil() {}

    static {
       sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getInstance() { return sessionFactory; }

}
```

Comment: Ohh, silly me. Thanks, one problem is resolved. But what about the second one?

Comment: Added the solution for your second problem to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I specified now the database name in the entities xml file, and it's working. Now I have another question: This query I wrote, it's with lazy fetching? If is not, how can I do it?

Comment: @DaJackal, add the `lazy` attribute to the association mapping with the desired value of `true` or `false`. And if codescape solved your problem you should accept his/her answer.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazy

Comment: Thanks for everyone for your help. @codescape, if I have multiple Hibernate Sessions, and I call everytime the getInstance() method everytime I need the sessionFactory, it's not the same thing? I could use some explanation here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define the database/schema name inside the server. Currently you specify only the database server.

```
<property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DATABASENAME</property>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I specified now the database name in the entities xml file, and it's working. Now I have another question: This query I wrote, it's with lazy fetching? If is not, how can I do it?